# $ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = k$ with $0 \leq k<1 $ find the nature of $\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

let$ \:f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ continious

$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} =  k$ with $0 \leq k<1  $

find the nature of $\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(t)dt$

using the definition of the limit, it exists $(A,α) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\times [0;1[ 
$ such as $ \forall x \geq A, \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} \leq α$
using recurence we have $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N},\forall x \geq A, f(x+n) \leq α^n f(x) $, thus $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(x+n)=0$ with $x \geq A $ set, thus  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$

then we have, $\frac{f(n+1+x)}{f(n+x)} \leq \frac{α^{n+1}}{α^n}$ thus (comparaison with a geometric serie) $\sum f(x+n) $converges with $x \geq A $ set

To sum up $\exists A \in \mathbb{R}_{+} : \forall x \geq A, \sum f(x+n) $converges
and I cannot go further;

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x\geq A$. Then you can use your idea of the geometric series to trap the integral along the tail between two Riemann sums, one with left end point method and the other with right end point method. This is essentially the integral test.

Obviously, $f$ integrates on $[0,a)$ since $f$ is continuous and the set is bounded.